# how to style web page 'select' drop down option for mobile phone app

Tags: android, mobile, drop-down-menu, html-select

Having a server page which has select dropdown option. When loaded on Android phone, different os version it has different style, i.e. on os 4.4 the dropdown list shows highlight for the selected item, but on os ver > 5 it shows no highlight for selected item with darkgrey background.

is there a way to control the style so on mobile phone would have same style? The snippet is what tried but does not work.

```
<div class="selectStyle”>
    <select>
        <option>option one</option>
        <option>option two</option>
    </select>
</div>

.selectStyle {
    border: 0px solid #ccc;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ebebeb   url("data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhDwAUAIABAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAEALAAAAAAPABQAAAIXjI+py+0Po5wH2HsXzmw//lHiSJZmUAAAOw==") no-repeat 90% 50%;
}

.selectStyle select {    
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    width: 100%;
}

.selectStyle select:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Could you post sceenshots of the output you are describing?

Which of the two styles is the correct one?

Comment: not sure how to post screenshot here, any idea?